# How to open Email configuration Sheet programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I can check if email clients are configured on the iPhone with this:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    // Actions to send mail
}
else
{
    //Actions to show an error message by UIAlertView
}
```

**How can I redirect the user to the email account configuration sheet I there is no email account configured?**

Answer (score 2):

You are able to open preferences app, but not more. Starting from iOS8, simply use this:

```
NSURL *settingsAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:settingsAppURL];
```